# Windows installer: How to supress Installation Incomplete window when search condition is not met

Tags: visual-studio-2010, search, registry, windows-installer

VS2010, Setup Project 
I add a Search64bitOffice property in Search Target Machine,

Name Search64bitOffice
Property: OFFICEIS64BIT
RegKey: Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Bitness
Root vsdrrHKLM
Value: x64

Then I add a launch condition Search64bitOffice
Condition: OFFICEIS64BIT 
Message: This installer only works for 64 bit Office.

When I try installer on Win 7 64 bit + Office 32 bit,  a window pops up saying "This installer only works for 64 bit Office" which is expected. 
I click OK to dismiss the window, then another window comes up 
saying 
Installation Incomplete 
The installer was interrupted before *** could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again.  Click close to exit.

I do not want the second window to show up. How to remove it from installer? thanks

another question: how to use the reverse condition, say when the condition is false, I want installer to continue? I tried ~OFFICEIS64BIT, do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want the second window to show up. How to remove it from
>   installer?

You can't remove it. It's the user exit dialog which is shown when the installation is cancelled by the user or a launch condition.

The most you can do is modify it, but this is not supported by Visual Studio.

> how to use the reverse condition, say when the condition is false, I
>   want installer to continue?

Use NOT to negate the condition:

```
NOT OFFICEIS64BIT
```

Comment: Sorry, meant adding comment but accidentally added an answer.  "NOT OFFICEIS64BIT" does not work. I tried My installer on a PC with 64 bit Excel, it should stop but it does not. It just behaves the same way when I install it on a PC with 32 bit Excel

Comment: Try creating a verbose log to see what value OFFICEIS64BIT has: http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log . If it's being set, then you need to find out why.

Comment: Thanks agin, Cosmin. due to limitation of comment, I put log file in my answer. It looks like OFFICEIS64BIT return true. but "NOT" is ignored in condition. thanks

Comment: The property is not set by AppSearch action because the registry entry is not found. So the launch condition works correctly. Visual Studio registry searches use only the 32-bit registry hive. They don't have support for the msidbLocatorType64bit flag which makes them search the 64-bit hive. So most likely Office x64 doesn't use a 32-bit registry entry with the path you specified. A solution would be to add the flag manually by editing the MSI with Orca. Another solution would be to use a different setup authoring tool which offers more support for this.

Comment: Not sure why it is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Bitness, I think it should be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Bitness, where does the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32 come from?

Comment: Thanks Cosmin.  What value should I change in msi with Orca to make it work?

Comment: Type column in RegLocator table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371171(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks. Just tried set Type to 18 in RegLocator. this time I got MSI (c) (B4:C0) [16:24:02:860]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Bitness 3: 2 
MSI (c) (B4:C0) [16:24:02:860]: Note: 1: 2262 2: IniLocator 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (B4:C0) [16:24:02:860]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DrLocator 3: -2147287038 ,  looks like the condition is not met, but I verify in registry, it has x64 in bitness.  Sth still missing? thanks

Comment: It looks like the condition is not set. but based on what I see in registry, it should be set.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in Launch Condition

!(OFFICEIS64BIT)

I had similar problem & it worked.